# Copy from a website to a specific cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to access a site, copy data from Excel to the site, hit click and then copy the result.

I'm stuck at copying the result from the website to Excel.

```
Set Element = appIE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("col-12 encryptedMsg")
Cells(1, 1) = Element.innertext
```

I receive

> Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

This error I think is for `.innertext`.

This is the part from the site and it's supposed to copy:

```
Sjl6U2REUzZnYXE5MkE4ZHJ0Q0ZtUT09OllZbGVsT05CTE52cnZpREo0anNiZmc9PQ==
```

on the first cell.

```html
<div class="row">
  <!-- Alert box with response -->
  <div class="col-12 mt-5 alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <u>Encrypted text:</u>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 encryptedMsg">
        Sjl6U2REUzZnYXE5MkE4ZHJ0Q0ZtUT09OllZbGVsT05CTE52cnZpREo0anNiZmc9PQ==
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have:

```vb
Sub Browsetosite()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

With appIE
    .Navigate "The website"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

appIE.Document.getElementByID("encryptionKey").Value = Cells(1, 2).Value
appIE.Document.getElementByID("plainText").Value = Cells(1, 3).Value
   
With appIE.Document

    Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems

        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Encrypt") Then
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If

    Next e

End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set Element = appIE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("col-12 encryptedMsg")
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = Element.innertext

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to test your code with a proper url...

```
Set Elements = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("col-12 encryptedMsg")
If Elements.Length > 0 Then
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = Elements(0).innerText
End If
```

getElementsByClassName returns a collection. Here you modify the 1rst item.
Up to you :)

Comment: One problem fix but I have another one. Initially I've tested the code only for a row, now that I have the entire code, I've encountered another issue. It's regarding the lines below. So for the first cell, it's generating a key from 12 characters but for the next line it's generating the same 12 characters plus another 12 characters and so on.
'For iCount = 1 To 12
        If Int((2 * Rnd) + 1) = 1 Then
            rString = rString & Chr(Int(26 * Rnd + 65))
        Else
             rString = rString & Int(10 * Rnd)
        End If
        
    Next iCount
    Cells(J, 10) = rString'